# Is there a way to return a generic supertype without casting in Java?

Tags: java, generics

Say I have these classes:

```
interface Field<T> {}

interface Function<T> extends Field<T> {}

interface UnaryFunction<INPUT, OUTPUT> extends Function<OUTPUT> {}

class UnaryFunctionImpl<INPUT, OUTPUT> implements UnaryFunction<INPUT, OUTPUT> {

  public Function<INPUT> asField() {
    return (Function<INPUT>) this;
  }

}
```

Why does `asField()` require a cast? Is this in some way theoretically unsound, or is the compiler just not smart enough?

Comment: Its not really a problem, I'm just curious if the the type system lets me do this without casting.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is no. Because `Function<INPUT>` and `Function<OUTPUT>` are different types, so you have to tell compiler that you take responsibility for your action.

Comment: Sorry, I just realized it should be `Function<INPUT>`, not `Function<OUTPUT>`. The real code is much more complex, I fixed my example.

Comment: In this case no casting required.

Comment: ... not even the method would be required then. Any instance of `UnaryFunction<X,Y>` is already a `Function<X>`.

Comment: Thats what I thought, but I get a compiler error in IntelliJ: `Incompatible types. Required: Function<INPUT>, Found: UnaryFunction<INPUT, OUTPUT>`.

Comment: I tried it and it works fine. Perhaps your real code is have something that missing in your example.

Comment: Same here. I'll ty to find out.

Comment: In this case my answer is correct. You can't skip casting.

Comment: Damn you're right. This might actually be a bug, I'll have to investigate. Thanks nevertheless!

Comment: Note that I feel like the question should be deleted, because the premise is wrong. But since it has answers, I can't.

Comment: @MichaelBöckling don't worry about it. You question is correct (even if you understand what is causing problem now) so you don't need to delete it.

Comment: @MichaelBöckling you can try to close it yourself as "Off-topic" -> ":a problem that can no longer be reproduced". But I'm not sure if it works.

Answer (score 1):

The `UniaryFunction<INPUT, OUTPUT>` is a `Function<OUTPUT>` but **NOT** a `Function<INPUT>`, so **the cast is wrong** unless INPUT and OUTPUT are the same type.

If the input and output type are the same, the code would be:

```
class UnaryFunction<T, T> extends Function<T> {
  public Function<T> asSupertype() {
    return this;
  }
}
```

... which renders the casting and `asSupertype()` obsolete.